# How to customize md break point for a single material ui Grid instance using css

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using material ui [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) for responsive ui.

```
<Grid spacing={2} xs={12} container={true}>
  <Grid item={true} lg={4} md={6} sm={12}>...</Grid>
  <Grid item={true} lg={4} md={6} sm={12}>...</Grid>
  <Grid item={true} lg={4} md={6} sm={12}>...</Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want to customize the screen width for breakpoint `md` to `npx` and I want to do it only in this one instance. Not throught the app.

I found how to do it for the entire app and also for a single grid instance using styles.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: npx,
    },
  },
});
```

But would prefer doing it using css instead of material ui styles. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `your-class` to the each item. Then use this css:

```css
@media (min-width:960px) { //change min-width to your selected value
  .MuiGrid-grid-md-6.your-class {
    flex-grow: 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

That works if your new breakpoint is `< 960px`. If the value is `> 960px`, you **also** need this:

```css
@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:959px) { //change max-width to (your selected value - 1)
  .MuiGrid-grid-sm-12.your-class {
    flex-grow: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

You can use the same reasoning for other breakpoints as well. E.g: For `lg`, which the default breakpoint is `1280px`:

```css
@media (min-width:1280px) {//change min-width to your selected value
  .MuiGrid-grid-lg-4.your-class {
    flex-grow: 0;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.333333%;
  }
}

// If breakpoint > 1280px, also add

@media (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1279px) { //change max-width to (your selected value - 1)
  .MuiGrid-grid-md-6.your-class {
    flex-grow: 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

Further customisation would depend on which values you set, i.e. `lg={4}` vs `lg={3}`... I've pasted the full css definitions for `MuiGrid` [here](https://pastebin.com/wt4PF5Wr).